# Trouble Adding PDF Template to FDF

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, fdf

I'm using the FDFToolkit for Java and it has a method for the class FDFDoc called AddTemplate().

It is throwing an exception for me because the FDF I created with FDFToolkit is apparently a classic FDF as opposed to the expected "template-based" FDF.

I have done endless amounts of searching and can't find the difference between the two let alone how one is supposed to use the AddTemplate method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The use of Templates in FDF is explained in the Portable Document Format Reference (best version 1.7, which is provided in the Acrobat SDK documentation); you may also have a look at ISO 32000. You use the Template key in an FDF only if the base PDF has a matching Template defined. You define Template pages in Acrobat (Pro). In Acrobat XI, you find that in the Tools Panel, Document processing pane, Page Templates.

Comment: Thanks Max! I've created a form in Acrobat Pro that I'm trying to use as the template for my FDF. I want the FDF data and PDF form template to be merged together into one PDF so that users can download and actually be able to read the generated data as opposed to it being in FDF form linked to an external template (they won't have the template on their local file system so the F key won't find the linked template).

Is there something wrong with the way I've done this thus far in creating a PDF fillable form and using that to try and AddTemplate to the generated FDF?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The term "Template" has a very specific meaning in PDF, which is not what is normally understood as "form template" or "template document" by the laymen. What you want to do, obviously, is prefill a form where the base PDF is on a server, using a data file on the server. If I am not too wrong, you can use an URI as argument of the /F key; otherwise, use the relative path from the FDF (one of them should work). Or, you do server-side filling, using either a library (such as iText) or an application (such as FDFMerge by Appligent).